# C# Code-First not recognizing data annotations

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

When I use `Update-Database`, it generally runs just fine and I see my changes on the SQL side.  When I created the model, all properties used `Required`, but after removing this annotation, the mapped column is still `not null`.  I've tested my migration setup by adding and removing columns, this works fine.

My model is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Company.Employees {

    [Serializable]
    [Table("EmployeeRecords")]
    public class EmployeeRecords {

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date Submitted")]
        public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Processed")]
        public DateTime? DateProcessed { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Submitted By")]
        public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Employees")]
        public Int16 Employees { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Total Wages")]
        public decimal TotalWages { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Total Benefits")]
        public decimal TotalBenefits { get; set; }

        public List<EmployerReference> EmployerReferences { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You'll see the property `DateProcessed` isn't `[Required]`.  But EF isn't seeing this.

I also tested using other data annotations.  I added `[MaxLength(450)]`, then ran Update-Database.  This worked, in SQL the mapped column changed to `VARCHAR(450)`

It's possible I'm way off, this is my first application using code-first.  Please let me know if any more information is required.  Thanks!!

**Edit:**

I just tried using Fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RemittanceBatch>().Property(m => m.DateProcessed).IsOptional();
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

This didn't work, either.

**Edit 2:**

It allows me to make the `DateSubmitted` field nullable.  But does NOT allow me to make the `DateProcessed` field nullable.  What's the difference here... hmm

Comment: I think you need to use `[Column()]` not `[Display()]`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns#data-annotations

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I wasn't aware this existed.  I did try adding this just now and no change. It seems like the columns are mapped just fine automatically

Comment: Have a look at your migration `Up()` and `Down()` and see what it's doing.

Comment: I came across something about Up() and Down() while I was doing research.  I'll look further into that.

Comment: The methods are empty, for one thing lol

Answer (score 0):

So, I may never figure out what the actual problem was.  I'm willing to just call it a bug at this point.  Here's what fixed it.

- Remove the property from the model
- Run `Update-Database`.
- Add the property again
- Run `Update-Database`.

Magic!  It Works!